# Trouble installing Pygame on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I've installed Python 2.7 and Pygame on my Mac, but every time I try to 'import pygame', I get this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical architecture issue. Try a

```
file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
```

If one of the result lines includes your architecture (e.g. i386), then the problem is not from the package itself, but from the way you launched it. Try then to launch it from a 32 bits instance of Python:

```
python2.7-32
>>>import pygame
```

NB: you can guess your architecture with

```
uname -m
```